# Help with SharePoint 2010 Calculated Column IF AND Statement

Tags: calculated-column

Having trouble with this calculated column.  Can someone convert this to SharePoint syntax please?

```
IF[ RES] = ISBLANK AND [SCHEDDTTM] = ISBLANK 
  THEN “NOT REMOVED”
  ELSE IF [ RES] =ISBLANK AND [SCHEDDTTM]  = NOT BLANK 
    THEN “SCHEDULED FOR REMOVAL”
      ELSE IF [ RES]  = “CANCEL”  AND [COMPDTTM] = NOT BLANK 
        THEN “CANCELED”
        ELSE IF [ RES]  = NOT BLANK AND [COMPDTTM]  = NOT NULL 
          THEN “REMOVED”
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint if else takes following form

```
=IF(condition, true, false)
```

So your formula can be something as below

```
=if(and(isblank(res),isblank(scheddttm)), 
        "NOT REMOVED", 
    if(
        isblank(res),
            if(isblank(scheddttm), 
                if(and(res="CANCEL",ISBLANK(COMPDTTM)), 
                    "CANCELED", 
                if(isblank(res), 
                    "", 
                if(isblank(COMPDTTM), 
                    "", 
                "REMOVED"))), 
            "SCHEDULED FOR REMOVAL")))
```